# Is "fill in the variable with" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "fill in the variable with" idiomatic?

For example:

> I didn't fill in the variable with a custom value yet, don't use it.
>
> I didn't fill in the variable with a custom function yet, don't use
>   it.

I am not sure if we can use fill in in order to say write something and assign it to it, or fill a value inside an empty bracket or already written equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "idiomatic", but I don't really think you mean "idiomatic" either. This is *terminology*.

I believe the *correct terminology* you are looking for is "*assign the variable a value*".

> I didn't assign the variable a custom value yet, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't fill the variable in* is the standard English for that phrase - moving the preposition to the end of the phrase. But the result is two prepositions bundled together (*in with*) which is awful stylistically - so it's really better to replace the *fill in* with another phrase or rephrase the whole thing:

- *set the variable to a custom value*
- *assign a value to the variable*
- *initialize the variable with...*
- *write the value into the variable*

and so on.